# scraping twitter followers selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, twitter, web-scraping

I am attempting to scrape the aliases of followers on several Twitter profiles with Python. When using the API I get rate-limited every 300 followers so I am looking for a faster way. I tried using Beautiful Soup but BS was not able to locate the html elements that contain information on individual followers, I assume this is because this portion of the page may be rendered via javascript.

Thus I tried to use Selenium and am still having trouble locating the elements in which follower information is contained.

The code below gives the following error, despite that there are elements with the class name "ProfileCard-content" that appear when View Source is selected from the referenced page:  "Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"ProfileCard-content"}"

```
from selenium import webdriver

path_to_chromedriver = '/Users/my_name/Desktop/chromedriver'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver)

url = 'https://twitter.com/odeszaaa/followers'

browser.get(url)

browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

el = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='ProfileCard-content']")
```

Any ideas as to why I can't locate this element among others?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter uses lazy loading, loading until the point at which it is needed.
I would try to scroll till the bottom of the page:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

then after that try using the find, I also recommend to do search by xpath using the classname.

Comment: I tried both your suggestions and still get the following error message: "Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='ProfileCard-content']"}"

This is the code I used:

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

el = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='ProfileCard-content']")